# How to copy in two folders simultaneously using GNU parallel by spawning multiple threads?

Tags: linux, scripting, scp, gnu-parallel, multithreading

I am trying to copy files from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA` as I am running my below shell script on `machineA`.

If the files is not there in `machineB` then it should be there in `machineC` for sure so I will try copying the files from `machineB` first, if it is not there in `machineB` then I will try copying the same files from `machineC`.

I am copying the files in parallel using GNU Parallel library and it is working fine. Currently I am copying two files in parallel.

Earlier, I was copying the `PRIMARY_PARTITION` files in `PRIMARY` folder using GNU parallel and once that is done, then onnly I was copying the `SECONDARY_PARTITION` files in `SECONDARY` folder using same GNU parallel so it is sequential as of now w.r.t `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folder.

Now I decided to copy files in `PRIMARY` and `SECONDARY` folder simultaneously. Meaning, I will copy two files in `PRIMARY` folder along with two files in `SECONDARY` folder simultaneously.

Below is my shell script which I have -

```
#!/bin/bash

export PRIMARY=/test01/primary
export SECONDARY=/test02/secondary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
export FILERS_LOCATION_1=${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}
export FILERS_LOCATION_2=${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(550 274 2 546 278) # this will have more file numbers
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1643 1103 1372 1096 1369 1568) # this will have more file numbers

export dir3=/testing/snapshot/20140103

find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete
find "$SECONDARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

do_CopyInPrimary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInPrimary

do_CopyInSecondary() {
  el=$1
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $SECONDARY/.
}
export -f do_CopyInSecondary


parallel -j 2 do_CopyInPrimary ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
parallel -j 2 do_CopyInSecondary ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
wait

echo "All files copied."
```

**Problem Statement:-**

With the above script at some point I am getting this exception -

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Is there any better way of doing the same thing as the way I am doing currently? I guess, I can still use GNU Parallel to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is typically caused by too many ssh/scp starting at the same time. That is a bit odd as you at most run 4. That leads me to believe /etc/ssh/sshd_config:MaxStartups and MaxSessions on $FILERS_LOCATION_1+2 is set too low.

Luckily we can ask GNU Parallel to retry if a command fails:

```
do_Copy() {
  el=$1
  PRIMSEC=$2
  scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_1:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMSEC/. || scp david@$FILERS_LOCATION_2:$dir3/new_weekly_2014_"$el"_200003_5.data $PRIMSEC/.
}
export -f do_Copy

parallel --retries 10 -j 2 do_Copy {} $PRIMARY ::: "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
parallel --retries 10 -j 2 do_Copy {} $SECONDARY ::: "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}" &
wait

echo "All files copied."
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion again. Can you explain little bit how `$1` and `$2` is getting used here? And how does it know what is `$1` and what is `$2` And what does `:::` this means? Just little bit explanation will help me a lot.

Comment: Start by going through the tutorial: man parallel_tutorial